# SQL query to select records based on existence of required or lack of excluded values

Tags: sql

I'm hoping for some assistance in building a simple query that will return a list of names from a given table where an entry containing a required color exists and no entry containing an excluded color exists.

```
id  name     color
--- -------- --------
1   james    red
2   james    blue
3   james    green
4   jim      red
5   jim      purple
6   bob      white
7   bob      red
8   bob      pink
9   charlie  white
10  charlie  green
11  charlie  black
12  kate     violet
13  kate     pink
14  kate     red
```

I want to select all names where:

- there must be a 'red' entry, i.e. excluding charlie
- there must not be a 'pink' entry, i.e. excluding kate and bob

i.e.

- james - included, has red, does not have pink
- jim - included, has red, does not have pink
- bob - excluded, has red but also has pink, which is excluded
- charlie - excluded, does not have red
- kate - excluded, has red, but also has pink, which is excluded

Ideally the output would include the list of distinct names (i.e. james, jim) and the query would allow me to use lists of colors for the required or excluded colors.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name
from t
where color in ('pink', 'red')
group by name
having min(color) = 'red' and min(color) = max(color);
```

This version just limits the colors to `'pink'` and `'red'`.  The `having` clause checks that only one color is present for a name, and that that color is `'red'`.

Comment: That's an interesting solution.

Comment: @JWeezy . . . Not only "interesting", but it also answers the question.

Comment: Can this be amended to support lists of required colors and lists of excluded colors?

Comment: @joelc . . . Yes, but that would be a *different* question and should be asked as a new question.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff because of you pointing out that the previously selected answer did not actually provide the solution, I updated the question and removed the checkmark so I could accept a new solution.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff - here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496661/sql-query-to-select-records-based-on-required-or-excluded-values

Comment: @joelc . . . I thought you had a question about *lists* of colors and excluded colors.

Comment: Yes: ```and the query would allow me to use lists of colors for the required or excluded colors.```.  For the answer in the other question, I could easily substitute ```color in (...)```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the IN and NOT IN operator in the WHERE clause. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column_1 IN ('red')
AND column_1 NOT IN ('pink')
```

If the list of inclusions and exclusions are static then you can use the query above.

If the list is dynamic, such as a table that stores the inclusion and exclusion lists, then you can replace the static values with a SELECT statement.

Comment: @jelc . . . This does not answer the question.  It merely returns all rows that are `'red'`, including "kate".