# SQL query to select records based on required or excluded values

Tags: sql

Asking as a new question due to incorrectly accepting the wrong answer previously (see [SQL query to select records based on existence of required or lack of excluded values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482012/sql-query-to-select-records-based-on-existence-of-required-or-lack-of-excluded-v))

I'm hoping for some assistance in building a simple query that will return a list of names from a given table where an entry containing a required color exists and no entry containing an excluded color exists.

```
id  name     color
--- -------- --------
1   james    red
2   james    blue
3   james    green
4   jim      red
5   jim      purple
6   bob      white
7   bob      red
8   bob      pink
9   charlie  white
10  charlie  green
11  charlie  black
12  kate     violet
13  kate     pink
14  kate     red
```

I want to select all names where:

- there must be a 'red' entry, i.e. excluding charlie
- there must not be a 'pink' entry, i.e. excluding kate and bob

i.e.

- james - included, has red, does not have pink
- jim - included, has red, does not have pink
- bob - excluded, has red but also has pink, which is excluded
- charlie - excluded, does not have red
- kate - excluded, has red, but also has pink, which is excluded

Ideally the output would include the list of distinct names (i.e. james, jim) and the query would allow me to use lists of colors for the required or excluded colors.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Have case expressions in the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the NOT EXISTS function remove the cases where pink is there:

```
SELECT Distinct a.name
FROM Table a
WHERE Color='Red'
    AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1
        FROM Table b
        WHERE a.Name=b.Name and b.Color='Pink')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @CR7SMS this is helpful